# How to start file writing from beginning after adding few lines In C or shell script

Tags: c, shell

I am currently trying to solve one issue. I want to add few lines in one txt file. let's say 20 lines. and with that I am checking how many lines has been added and once I reached to 20 lines, then again start adding lines from beginning of file. Means want to reset file pointer and start overwriting from first line.

I used echo command to add lines in file, which always keep appending file. But it doesn't reset file pointer.

I also tried to open file in append mode, but it doesn't allow to reset file pointer at the beginning of file.

W+ and r+ mode also not useful for me. Can someone suggest me solution for this? I mostly use C language or shell script.

Comment: Have you tried [rewind](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/)?

Comment: Yes I tried rewind, but in append mode, that doesn't work..

Comment: Worked fine for me, could post a code sample and the text file you are experimenting with?

Comment: @KeyPare - If _in append mode, that doesn't work_, don't use append mode. It is a misconception that _W+ and r+ mode also not useful_. Are you aware that the lines must all have the same length for your plan to work? How are you _checking how many lines has been added_?

Answer (score 0):

**shell script:**
use command `sed` if you work with linux.
You can delete or replace a line first, second, fourth, what else. Powerfull!

use command `wc -l` to show how many lines you have.

**c code**
use `fseek` that is what you looking for.

Have fun to find your fav solution.

**My code to show it works with fseek**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void writeToFile(FILE*, char*);

int main(void)
{
    /* Mode: w or w+ //Content of file will be gone! */
    long pos;
    FILE* fhwrite = fopen("Lines.txt","w");
    writeToFile(fhwrite,"I'M 1.st line\n");
    writeToFile(fhwrite,"I'M 2.nd line\n");
    writeToFile(fhwrite,"I'M 3.rd line\n");
    
    /* Position of line 4 */
    pos = ftell(fhwrite);
    writeToFile(fhwrite,"I'M 4.th line\n");
    
    writeToFile(fhwrite,"I'M 5.th line\n");

    fseek(fhwrite,pos,SEEK_SET);
    /*
        Windows: \r\n | 2 Bytes more for replace
        Linux: \n     | 1 Byte more for replace
    */
    writeToFile(fhwrite,"REWRITE  LINE  4\n");
    fclose(fhwrite);
}

void writeToFile(FILE* fh, char* putTextToFile)
{
    printf("Current position: %ld\n", ftell(fh));
    fprintf(fh, "%s", putTextToFile);
}
```

***conclusion | Result:***

You must read the whole file, replace the spezific line.
All changes done you can write it back to a file.

I think a bash script is much easier for your operation (IF LINUX) ^^.

Comment: But if I open file in append mode, fseek doens't reset file pointer to start of file...

Comment: Also once I reach adding few lines in file, I want to start from top of file. So every time code runs, it should just keep adding from where last it left. For ex :- it adds 20 lines, than if I run code again, it will check already 20 line, then start adding from 1st line and keep moving...

Comment: @KeyPare You must read your file line by line. Check array if 20 lines reached if not then append it to the array and write it down into a file. My example code only works because it write 1st line by line. If we reopen it - the programm forgot all operations. Keep this in mind. Have a nice day. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using fseek with SEEK_SET?
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.html